# Spark GraphX spark-shell vs spark-submit performance differences

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

We have written some code to join and link datasets via GraphX written in Scala using Spark 1.6.1 and Scala 2.10.

If we run this code in spark-shell it will complete in 30mins with 10 executors, 10g memory & 5 cpu per executor.

If we run this in a fat jar with spark-submit then the process falls over with out of memory errors and takes an hour and a half to get to that point.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

Does anyone know how the SparkContext and SQLContext are setup in the shell and if we have missed out anything in setting up our own Contexts which might be causing the issue with the spark-submit running so badly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out a while back and just bumped into my question again. So thought would update with how I fixed it. The issue was not a difference between spark-submit and spark-shell but difference in the code structure we were executing.

In the Shell i was unbundling the code and executing it line by line, this resulted in the code generated by Spark being fast and efficient.

With Spark Submit we had packaged up the code and rolled it into classes with Inheritence to make the code easier to share and reuse, but this resulted in the code Spark generated being messy and inefficient. When we removed the majority of the Inheritance and wrote simpler more functional code the base the performance went back to being fast and efficient.

So the lesson here is to make sure you do not OOP your application too much and little inheritance is OK, but you should endeavour to keep your code as simple and functional ass possible to make it easy for Spark to generate fast efficient code to execute on the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference.

Check `spark-submit` settings - probably some of them are incorrect and `spark-submit` has lower number of executors or memory.

Open Spark Web UI, check if data is not skewed and if all configuration is correct

Comment: We have checked the settings they are identical and even if we give the spark-submit more resources than the shell it still runs into issues. Also if the data was skewed it should affect the shell and submit in the same way?

Comment: @AndyLong Could you check parameters' values in Spark Web UI?

Comment: Maybe some settings are overriden, that's why I want to check information from Web UI